# what occurs if an element is pushed onto an array during the execution of a loop through that array using the map method in javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Within my web application:

- I have an array that is updated realtime via firebase API.
- I have a user triggered method that loops though that array to
  retrieve elements based on a few given parameters.

What occurs if an element is pushed onto an array during the execution of a loop through that array using the map method in javascript?

Or to put it another way, can i assume that when using the map method to loop through an array, that the map method loops through a snapshot of the array?

I would like to avoid using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myArray))` to ensure that i am looping through a snapshot.

Can anyone offer code that can test this scenario for a definitive answer?

Comment: pretty much as you have asked array methods that do not mutate values actually return a copy of the array. This is a static copy so any changes afterward are not reflected in the return of methods like `.map()`, `.reduce()`, and `.filter()` to name a few. This behavior is ideal for using immutable data required by Functional Programming

Comment: I added a note to my answer. I doubt you need to worry about making a snapshot. Nothing can mutate the array during a call to `map` except the map callback itself. No asynchronous callbacks can run between map callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to test this; [The ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.map) is clear:

> The range of elements processed by map is set before the first call to callbackfn. Elements which are appended to the array after the call to map begins will not be visited by callbackfn. If existing elements of the array are changed, their value as passed to callbackfn will be the value at the time map visits them; elements that are deleted after the call to map begins and before being visited are not visited.

If you want to test you could use something like this:

```js
const arr = [5];

const result = arr.map( x => {
  console.log( `Visiting ${x}` );
  arr.push( x + 1 );
  return 2*x;
} );

console.log( arr ); // Has two elements

console.log( result ); // Only has one element
```

However, when you say:

> Or to put it another way, can i assume that when using the map method to loop through an array, that the map method loops through a snapshot of the array?

That is different from your previous wording. Elements that are pushed onto the array are not visited by map callbacks, but elements that have been replaced, will be their new value. You can test that like this:

```js
const arr = [0,0];

const result = arr.map( x => {
  console.log( `Visiting ${x}` );
  arr[1] = 3;
  return 2*x;
} );

console.log( result );
```

Note: [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is synchronous, and JavaScript is single-threaded, so if the code in callback doesn't mutate the array, it is not possible for the array to be mutated during iteration (other code, I.E. firebase, cannot run while map is running).

```js
const arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

// Change a random value in arr every 4 milliseconds
//    Emulates Firebase modifying the array
setInterval( function ( ) {
  arr[~~(Math.random()*6)] = Math.random( );
}, 4 );

// (async), Logs values after they've been modified
setTimeout( function ( ) {
  console.log( 'Logging array values after one second' );
  arr.map( x => console.log( x ) );
}, 1000 );

// Logs the values unmodified, async code, such as Firebase can't affect this
console.log( '(sync) with a 100ms spinlock between each map callback, to demonstrate that the array cannot be modified externally during the map.' );
arr.map( x => {
  console.log( x );
  const start = +new Date;
  while( +new Date < start + 100 ); // Wait for 100 milliseconds
} );
```